# how to properly eliminate a race condition in the code?

Tags: c++, multithreading

There is a piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
#include "unistd.h"

//#define PREPARE_FILE_TO_READ

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::mutex;
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::vector;
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::make_shared;
using std::mutex;
using std::atomic;
using std::lock_guard;
using std::unique_lock;
using std::thread;
using std::queue;
using std::condition_variable;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;

constexpr int NUM_THREADS = 4;
const int N = 100;
int NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE = 0;
atomic<int> NUMBER_OF_BYTES_READ(0);
atomic<int> NUMBER_OF_BYTES_WRITTEN(0);
mutex mut;

template <typename T>
class TSQueue{
  private:
    queue<T> m_queue;
    mutable mutex m_mutex;
    condition_variable m_cond;
  public:
    void push(T item){
      unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_mutex);
      m_queue.push(item);
      m_cond.notify_one();
      cout << "TSQueue::push()" << endl;
    }
    T pop(){
      unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_mutex);
      cout << "TSQueue::pop() A size=" << m_queue.size() << endl;
      m_cond.wait(lock,[this](){return !m_queue.empty();});
      T item = m_queue.front();
      m_queue.pop();
      cout << "TSQueue::pop() B" << " item=" << item << endl;
      return item;
    }
    int size() const {
      unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_mutex);
      int size = m_queue.size();
      return size;
    }
};

shared_ptr<TSQueue<char>> squeue = make_shared<TSQueue<char>>();

class SyncFile{
  public:
    SyncFile(const char *  _path):path(_path){
      out.open(path, std::ios::out);
    }
    void write(char ch){
      lock_guard<mutex> lock(m);
      out.put(ch);
      out.put('\n');
    }
    ~SyncFile(){
      out.close();
    }
  private:
    const string path;
    ofstream out;
    mutable mutex m;
};

shared_ptr<SyncFile> ofA = make_shared<SyncFile>("ofA.dat");
shared_ptr<SyncFile> ofB = make_shared<SyncFile>("ofB.dat");

bool is_last_char(){
  return (NUMBER_OF_BYTES_WRITTEN == NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE);
}

void get_data(){
  cout << "get_data THREAD ID=" << std::this_thread::get_id() << endl;
  ifstream in1("v1.dat");
  cout << "file size=" << NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE << " B" << endl;
  NUMBER_OF_BYTES_READ = 0;
  int count = 0;
  while(NUMBER_OF_BYTES_READ < NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE){
    char ch = in1.get();
    squeue->push(ch);
    NUMBER_OF_BYTES_READ++;
    count++;
    if(NUMBER_OF_BYTES_READ % 100 == 0)
      cout << "count=" << count << " NREAD=" << NUMBER_OF_BYTES_READ
       << " FILE_SIZE=" << NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE
       << " squeue.size()=" << squeue->size()
       << endl;
  }
} 

void process_data(){
  this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(100));
  while(true){
    ///lock_guard<mutex> lock(mut);
    if(squeue->size() > 0){
      char ch = squeue->pop();
      if(ch == 'A') ofA->write(ch);
      if(ch == 'B') ofB->write(ch);
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES_WRITTEN++;
    }
    if(is_last_char()) break;
  }
}

int main()
{
#ifdef PREPARE_FILE_TO_READ
  vector<char> v1(N, 'a');
  for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) v1[i] = 'A'+rand()%2;
  ofstream out1("v1.dat");
  out1.write((const char*) v1.data(), sizeof(char)*N);
  out1.close();
  exit(0);
#endif
  ifstream in1("v1.dat");
  in1.seekg(0, in1.end);
  NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE = in1.tellg();
  cout << "NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE="<<NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE << endl;
  in1.seekg(0, in1.beg);
  vector<char> vin1(N, '0');
  in1.read((char*) vin1.data(), sizeof(char)*N);
  int countA=0, countB=0;
  for(int i = 0; i < vin1.size(); ++i){
    if(vin1[i] == 'A')      countA++;
    else if(vin1[i] == 'B') countB++;
  }
  in1.close();
  vector<thread> tasks;
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS+1; ++i){
    if(i == 0) tasks.push_back(thread(get_data));
    else       tasks.push_back(thread(process_data));
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); ++i) tasks[i].join();
  cout << "countA=" << countA << " countB=" << countB << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

First, one opens (uncomments) the PREPARE_FILE_TO_READ flag, compiles and runs the mini app and the output file *v1.dat* is created, which consists of 'A' and 'B' *N* char symbols. Then this flag is closed (commented) and when the app is run, it hangs up with the most often last line of the output:

TSQueue::pop() A size=0

I suppose there is a data race in *process_data()* function: when thread A and thread B see squeue.size()>0 at the line

```
f(squeue->size() > 0)
```

and go inside this if statement block of code, immediately after this, say, thread A pops the last element and thread B tries to pop it a little bit later, but the queue is empty by the moment. That is why thread B is waiting due to the condition variable *m_cond* for the moment when queue->size() > 0 (but it will never occur, that is why the program hangs up). This is my understanding of the reason why the program is frozen (please, correct me if I'm wrong).
If to uncomment

```
lock_guard<mutex> lock(mut);
```

in *process_data()*, everything seems to work properly, but there is no multithreading then (as I understand).

Could You be so kind to tell me how to properly eliminate this race condition and fix this issue?

Comment: Your code is difficult to read because it's so... compact. Consider adding spaces around operators, literals, and identifiers. Also consider using  `using` declarations (with full-type-names, _not_ just namespaces)) to avoid having `std::` everywhere.

Comment: There a reason to not use a `mutex`? Looks like you commented out the `lock_guard` for some reason. After your edit, it still has multi-threaded ...

Comment: The ways to avoid race conditions are to use `std::atomic`s and synchronization primitives like `std::mutex`, etc.

Comment: Your `SyncFile.m` is a different `std::mutex` than your `TSQueue`'s `m_mutex`.

Comment: `get_data()` finishes its work when `process_data()` is not waiting for the conditional variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the *only* problem, but right now your TSQueue isn't really thread safe. Or at least there's virtually no way to use it that's free of race conditions anyway.

And your code reflects that. Right now, your process_data has:

```
if(squeue->size() > 0){
  char ch = squeue->pop();
```

Consider what's going to happen when you reach the last item in the queue, with two threads processing the data. Both threads execute the `if` statement and both see that there's at least one item left in the queue. Then both of them try to pop that item. One gets the item, and the other waits...forever.

In fact, a thread-safe queue normally should *not* have a `size()` member function (at least not a public one). Any use of it is pretty much a guaranteed race condition. And no, changing that to an `is_empty` or `is_not_empty` doesn't help at all.

Rather, the interface to a thread-safe queue should normally consist only of `push` and `pop`. But the `pop` is really more of a `try_pop`--it can fail.

There are a couple of choices about the exact circumstances under which it will fail. One is that if the queue is empty, it fails immediately. The other is that it can wait for up to some maximum period of time for there to be an item in the queue, and then fails if none has shown up in that time.

At least personally, I generally find the latter more useful. It can simulate the former by passing a timeout value of 0.

`condition_variable` has a `wait_for` member function that can wait for a condition to become true, or timeout after a specified period of time, which makes it easy to implement that behavior. With it, our `pop` could look something like this:

```cpp
bool pop(T& t, std::chrono::milliseconds const& dur = 200ms) {

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(locker_);

    if (!data_ready.wait_for(lock, dur, [data_&] { return !data_.empty(); })) {
        return false;
    }

    t = data_.front();
    data_.pop_front();
    return true;
}
```

Using this, `process_data` would become more like this:

```cpp
char ch;
if (!squeue.pop(ch))
    break;
    
// process ch

// I've left this here, but it's *probably* no longer needed.
if (is_last_char())
    break;
```

#### Efficiency

Although it's not related to race conditions, using multi-threading to process a single character of data at a time (and do minimal processing on each) is pretty nearly guaranteed to end up as a net loss. The overhead of communicating between threads is virtually guaranteed to be greater than any gain you can hope to get from multi-threading.

#### Summary

A thread-safe queue *normally* should no have any way for outside code to even attempt to retrieve its size or ask whether it's empty. Any code of the form `if (!queue.empty())` or `if (queue.size() > 0)` or anything similar is  pretty much guaranteed to lead to a race condition. The only (sort of) useful purpose I've seen for such a thing was to log the queue size to give you some idea if (for example) you weren't processing data as fast as it was produced, so the queue was constantly growing. But if you base any condition in it, that condition may have changed by the time you try to act on it (which is pretty much the definition of a race condition).

Comment: Excuse me, Sir, so, there is no way to return a T value or a shared_ptr from the pop method? Or it's possible to return shared_ptr and check that it is not NULL?

Comment: Returning a `T` directly leads to problems with exception safety--if copying the `T` throws, you've simply lost that item. Returning a `shared_ptr<T>` would be possible, but impose a lot of overhead. If you really want to do something like that, you probably want to return a `std::optional<T>`.